# Eye strain with new laptop (XPS 15 9570 w/ 1080p screen)

Tags: laptop, display

I purchased a XPS 15 9570 with the FHD (1080p) screen 4 days ago.

Previously I was using an XPS 13 9343 with the QHD (3200x1800) screen.  I got the occasional eye strain but nothing out of the ordinary.

With this new laptop, my eyes get strained and water-y within just 10-20 minutes of use.  I have not used the laptop without feeling some sort of eye strain within 30 minutes of use.

An hour later, my eyes look bloodshot red

It is incredibly bothersome and I am not clear why this is happening.

My theory on the cause is that the response time on this monitor feels extremely low.  It feels like it's 50-100 ms.

The ghosting on this display is very noticeable and I think the blurriness when scrolling/moving the screen around is causing my eye strain.

However I do feel my eyes getting strained looking at this display even when I'm not moving the screen around too much.

I know it's not caused by the environment because my work environment didn't change.  I tried adjusting the brightness/contrast/saturation but still same problem.

1. What could be causing my eye strain with this new display?
2. Maybe I just need to get used to this new display?  Or will I ever be able to?

Comment: Could be the refresh rate, perhaps some contaminant in the packaging, or something else. Since you've had the PC only four days, exchange it to see if another is better.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It is not the refresh rate I believe.  The screen is running at 60 Hz/fps.  The response rate on the other hand, is quite slow.

Comment: It also depends on the mains frequency - there can be subtle flicker if the frequencies differ by a few Hz.

Comment: If I read you correctly, you went from using a 23.6" monitor with the old laptop, to using the 15" laptop screen.  That would certainly lead to eye strain! If you mean you're still using the external monitor, now with the new laptop, please see if you can clarify the question.  I would have suggested the refresh rate as well, esp. as you say it's blurry and suffers ghosting. Or, the display driver on the new laptop may need to be updated ... or the graphics card has issues.

Comment: Try (at least temporarily to see if it works) changing the DPI displayed on the devices do that text/icons appear similarly sized. I found that doing this was a lot easier on my eyes when I changed monitors. Also if a monitor is blurry it's probably not running at native resolution. Ensure your computer can negotiate he correct resolution with 2 screens.

Comment: @Debra I edited the question.  I simplified the explanation to simply XPS 13 as I am still using the 23.6" monitor.  It's not the refresh rate.  It's 60Hz.  The main issue is the response time.  See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIh3DHYRUYQ).  Everything on the screen is very blurry when I'm moving it around.  I believe this blurriness is causing my problems.

Comment: @davidgo The monitor is only only blurry when I'm moving the screen around, such as scrolling down a wall of text.

Comment: I feel like the question is still a bit confusing -- it now seems to say that you're going from looking at a laptop that had 3200x1800 to looking at one with much lower resolution; is that correct?  In any case, I also see that reviews for this laptop include quite a few negative comments about the display.  As for the response time on the display, do you have ability to test with a different external monitor?  Also the product specs should contain that info somewhere.

Comment: This is a medical issue possibly triggered or exacerbated by technology. We are not really equipped to diagnose or suggest solutions to this sort of problem. Even if the display has ghosting/lag issues, that should not be sufficient to generate the medical issues you describe in the average person. We cannot advise you regarding either of the two questions you have placed in the original post.

Comment: @Debra Yes.  When I plug the XPS 15 into my 23.6" display (that has 5ms response time), it works perfectly and I get no problems.  This tells me it's not a graphics card / driver problem, rather a problem with the XPS 15's display.

Comment: @music2myear Fair enough.  Although I don't believe this is a medical issue because I have no eye strain problems using my XPS 13 or my external 23.6" monitor.

Comment: Any new discovery about this topic? I am suspecting WIFI card (Killer 1535) that is very strong in this model for eye strain. Antenas are inside screen. It can kill local router https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/XPS-15-9560-Killer-Wireless-killing-my-network/td-p/5095933.